# Why I get 30 fps in chrome dev tool performance panel, but JS and React both say it's 60?

Tags: reactjs, performance, html5-canvas, frame-rate, react-konva

I'm trying to use react to develop the classic game tutorial [how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game](http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-make-a-simple-html5-canvas-game/).

Everything went well until I found my movement is a little bit glitchy, [online test link](https://catchgoblins.netlify.com/) and [code](https://github.com/Stupidism/rummikub/tree/master/apps/waves).

[image]

While the original [game](http://www.lostdecadegames.com/demos/simple_canvas_game/) written in JS is much smoother:

[image]

So I dig into it a little bit and found the actual fps is different:

React:

[image]

Pure JS:
[image]

It is weird that after I added some code to calc fps I get "60 fps" in both react hook and useEffect:

```
// log interval in useEffect
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('interval', Date.now() - renderTime.current);
    renderTime.current = Date.now();
  });

// calc fps in hook directly
fps: rangeShrink(Math.round(1000 / (Date.now() - time.current)), 0, 60),

// render
         <Text 
          x={width - 120} 
          y={borderWidth} 
          text={`FPS: ${fps}`}
          fill="white"
          fontSize={24}
          align="right"
          fontFamily="Helvetica"
        />
```

[image]

## Locating The Problem

I added a contrasting canvas, which renders every time when `heroPos` is updated. It gets me 60FPS in the chrome dev tool. Now the problem is definitely caused by the canvas library I'm using: react-konva.

```
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d');
    if (backgroundStatus === 'loaded') {
      ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0);
    }
    if (heroStatus === 'loaded') {
      ctx.drawImage(heroImage, heroPos.x, heroPos.y);
    }
  }, [backgroundStatus, heroStatus, heroPos]);
```

## Located the problem

I located the problem, it's caused by the [batchDraw](https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/blob/9b3b2f4ecb446fe21f6370c4d33be854b5bd1d74/src/makeUpdates.js#L109) `react-konva` used:

After changing this line, I can get 60fps movement now.

```
-  drawingNode && drawingNode.batchDraw();
+  drawingNode && drawingNode.draw();
```

According to their [doc](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.BaseLayer.html#batchDraw), batchDraw would draw in `the next animationFrame`. But `react` itself also uses `RAF` to trigger the next props update, so the `batchDraw` here happens `2 frames` after I `setHeroPos()`.

## Solution:

I'm gonna submit a [pull-request](https://github.com/konvajs/react-konva/pull/448) to their project.

Comment: You should post a self answer with what you found instead of adding it as an edit. It may very well be useful to future readers as well and it explains better why 30FPS instead of 60FPS than the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dev tools can add a lot of additional load on the device. Much more so when you are recording a performance log.

React is the last thing I would use for a real-time app as it adds allot of  behind the scene JS to even simplest tasks.

Calculating performance by measuring the time between frames does not give you an accurate indication of performance.

### Performance

To measure the performance of a function use the [`performance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) API. The simplest way is via [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) using it to get the time a function takes to complete.

For example to get the time of the main loop function in a game

```
function mainLoop(frameTime) {
    const now = performance.now(); // MUST BE FIRST LINE OF CODE TO TEST!!!!

    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    const executeTime = performance.now() - now; // MUST BE LAST LINE OF CODE TO TEST!!!
}
```

This will give you a time to execute in milliseconds. Because JS is blocking only the code within the two lines are measured.

- **Note** NO addition overhead is measured, such as GC, Compositing, synchronous loading, etc...
- **Note** milliseconds (1/1,000,000th)
- **NOTE** the precision of this value [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) has [deliberately been reduced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now#Reduced_time_precision) to protect users, and is anywhere from 100ms - 200ms depending on the browser (1ms can be accessed behind flags and system configuration))

### Meaningful performance

JS execution is non deterministic which makes a single timing measure completely unreliable. (Reason why its better to use [`performance.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) than [`peformance.mark`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/mark))

To overcome JS execution non determinism and timer inaccuracy use a running mean to time your code. The example below shows how to do this.

Rather than show the time use a metric that relates to the needs of the application. For example how much of a frame is spent executing code. (see example)

### Example

This example animates some canvas content using `requestAnimationFrame`.

The slider lets you select the approx amount of time the function should spend rendering.

The Info text at the top shows the timing results as a running mean.

You will note that the Idealized Frame Load (IFL) is well below 100% before the frame rate drops.

#### Experiments

1. How does Dev Tools and performance monitoring effect performance.

Move the slider to just below when the frame rate drops below 60.

Open dev tools to see if and how it can effect apparent performance. Take note of any changes. IS there is an effect, and if so how much?

Record a performance log and see if the FPS and or IFL are effected by the recording

2. What is the max time your device can allocate to rendering before the frame rate is effected.

Move the slider slowly to the right.

When the frame rate drops below 60 move the slide back a step until it reads 60FPS again.

The values **IFL** will give the % of a perfect frame (60th second) executing code . **Time** absolute execution time in ms.

```js
Math.rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
Math.randItem = arr => arr[Math.random() * arr.length | 0];
CPULoad.addEventListener("input",() => loadTimeMS = Number(CPULoad.value));
var loadTimeMS = Number(CPULoad.value);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);

function mainLoop(frameTime) {

    /* Timed section starts on next line */
    const now = performance.now();
    
    CPU_Load(loadTimeMS);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
    
    const exeTime = performance.now() - now;
    /* Timed section ends at above line*/

    measure(info, frameTime, exeTime);
    
}

const measure = (() => {
    const MEAN = (t, f) => t += f;
    const fTimes = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], bTimes = [...fTimes];
    var pos = 0, prevTime, busyFraction;
    return (el, time, busy) => {
        if (prevTime) {
            bTimes[pos % bTimes.length] = busy;  
            fTimes[(pos ++) % fTimes.length] = time - prevTime;  
            const meanBusy = bTimes.reduce(MEAN, 0) / bTimes.length;
            const meanFPS = fTimes.reduce(MEAN, 0) / fTimes.length;
            el.textContent = "Load: " + loadTimeMS.toFixed(1) + "ms " +
                " FPS: " + Math.round(1000 / meanFPS) + 
                " IFL: " + (meanBusy / (1000 / 60) * 100).toFixed(1) + "%" +
                " Time: " + meanBusy.toFixed(3) + "ms";
            busyFraction = meanBusy / (1000/60);
        }
        prevTime = time;
    };
})();

const colors = "#F00,#FF0,#0F0,#0FF,#00F,#F0F,#000,#FFF".split(",");
// This function shares the load between CPU and GPU reducing CPU
// heating and preventing clock speed throttling on slower systems.
function CPU_Load(ms) { // ms = microsecond and is a min value only
   const now = performance.now();
   ctx.globalAlpha = 0.1;
   do {
      ctx.fillStyle = Math.randItem(colors);
      ctx.fillRect(Math.rand(-50,250), Math.rand(-50, 100), Math.rand(1, 200), Math.rand(1,100))
   } while(performance.now()-now <= ms);
   ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
#info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background: white;
    font-size:small;
    width:345px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
#canvas {
    background: #8AF;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#CPULoad {
    font-family: arial;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 10px;
    color: black;
    width: 340px !important;
}
```

```html
<code id="info"></code>
<input id="CPULoad" min="0" max="36" step="0.5" value="2"  type="range" list="marks"/>
<canvas id="canvas" width="350"></canvas>
<datalist id="marks">
  <option value="0"></option>
  <option value="4"></option>
  <option value="8"></option>
  <option value="12"></option>
  <option value="16"></option>
  <option value="20"></option>
  <option value="24"></option>
  <option value="28"></option>
  <option value="32"></option>
  <option value="36"></option>
</datalist>
```

**NOTE** The display of the times does effect the results. The fact this code is running in a sand boxed snippet will effect the results. For the most acurate results run code on on an independent page. Record results to JS data structure and display results after a test run.

- **Load**: Requested CPU/GPU execution load in 1/1000th second.
- **FPS**: Running mean Frames Per Second.
- **IFL**: Idealized Frame Load, percent of 60th second executing code.
- **Time**: Mean measured execution time in 1/1000th second.

Comment: React can be good for react. You just have to think about the performance a lot, e.g. PureComponents, React.memo etc.

Comment: Good explanation. I tried `performance.now()` instead and it ended up showing me a more accurate time(from 16ms to 16.213123ms). But this doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: @Stupidism 16ms is too long. The example code will give you an estimate of how long a frame can take to maintain a constant frame rate. For an average device its around ~60 - 70%, this drops for low end and is higher for top end devices. The reason is that the browser needs time to do its thing (compositing, possible re flows, events, GC, and more). I did hint a solution, React is not suited for real-time apps

Comment: @Blindman67 Thanks for your patient explanations. Thank you for not just debugging for me, but teaching and guiding me to find the answer.

Comment: "Note: milliseconds (1/1,000,000th) NOTE: the precision of this value performance.now [...] is anywhere from 100ms - 200ms". Hum what? FF has the biggest rounding factor with a only a single ms. Chrome has some jitter but is still at some μs precision. 200ms precision would make a stop watch more useful :-)